# Discord bot 'connect' command with discordjs v13, @discordjs/voice & SlashCommandBuilder

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently stuck with following problem: my test 'connect' command doesn't work if I try to execute it in Discord. Normal reply commands are working fine with the current build, but I can't figure out how to do voice channel shenanigans.
Here is the code of my 2 files:
(can post the ***deploy-commands.js*** too if needed, bit its the same code like in the discord.js guide)

**EDIT #1:** With *GentleAutumnRain* help I could resolve the first error, I changed all code snippets accordingly.

**EDIT #2:** fixed, bot is now joining the VC

***connect.js*** v3 //the test command

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const voiceDiscord = require('@discordjs/voice'); //3.change[GentleAutumnRain]

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('connect')
        .setDescription('The bot will connect to your voice channel!'),
        execute: async (interaction, client) => { //1.change[GentleAutumnRain]
            const channel = interaction.member.voice.channel;
            //Error case handling
            if(!channel) return interaction.channel.send('Please join a Voice Channel first!');
    
            const player = voiceDiscord.createAudioPlayer();
            const resource = voiceDiscord.createAudioResource('');
    
            const connection = voiceDiscord.joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: channel.id,
                guildId: interaction.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            });
    
            player.play(resource);
            connection.subscribe(player);
    
            // checking for ending, leaving VC if true
            /*player.on(voiceDiscord.AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
                connection.destroy();
            });*/
        },
};
```

***index.js*** v2 //main

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const fs = require('fs');

const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES] }); //2.change[GentleAutumnRain]
client.commands = new Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    // Set a new item in the Collection
    // With the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    client.user.setActivity(" YOU!", {type: "WATCHING"});
});
// Main - waiting for interaction
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    // Return error if a false command was typed
    if (!command) return;
    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token - MUST be always at the end of this script!
client.login(token);
```

**TERMINAL OUTPUT** if 'connect' is executed:

<s>Already tried to sub 'user' with 'member' but the result is the same.</s>

**NEW:**

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\DiscordBot_REPO> node .\index.js
Ready!
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createAudioPlayer')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\DiscordBot_REPO\commands\connect.js:13:41)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\DiscordBot_REPO\index.js:34:17)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\DiscordBot_REPO\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:66:12) 
    at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\DiscordBot_REPO\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\DiscordBot_REPO\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:350:31)    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\DiscordBot_REPO\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)        
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\DiscordBot_REPO\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)       
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\DiscordBot_REPO\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
```

This is my first question on this site, so if someone has critique how the question was written please let me know.
Anyways I would be grateful if someone could give me a helping hand in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right in changing it to `interaction.member.voice.channel`, that is how it will work, but you have to supply `interaction` properly to your `connect` command.

Right now, as you can see on this line `execute: async (client, interaction) => {` in your `connect.js` you are asking for two parameters, but when you attempt to execute this function on this line `await command.execute(interaction);` you only supply one. In javascript this is fine and the code will still work, but it is a first come first serve kind of deal. The interaction parameter you supply will be given to the first parameter you require in the `execute` command or in simpler words: The `interaction` you give as a parameter is being stored in the `client` variable in your execute function.

You can solve this simply switching the `client` and `interaction` parameter around in your `execute` command thereby allowing your `interaction` to slip into the right variable.

Additionally, in order to connect to a voice channel and do a lot of the related work you will need to supply you client with the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent. Simply add `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES` in the array of intents of your client in the `index.js` file and you're golden.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! I changed everything like you said, but now I get another TypeError -> 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createAudioPlayer')

Can post the whole log if you want, or should I edit the main post for this?

Comment: Edited the main post with your changes for a better reading experience and with the new terminal log.

Comment: @Niuoduab That's because you are importing the library of @discordjs/voice wrong. Only use the curly brackets if you are importing specific functions or variables. If you want it as a whole library that you can then reference functions from (like you are doing with `voiceDiscord.createAudioPlayer()` for example) then remove the curly brackets and just store it in a variable.